What are the Garmin G-1000 LRUs exactly? Where are they located?
During my IFR flight training I was told to check the LRU status on the G1000 of the Cessna 172 I was flying. On the G1000 this is displayed as a list with many options showing a green tick or not. Now I am wondering how LRUs actually work and are integrated with the G1000 and their respective location within the aircraft?

Adding to @John answer.
LRUs for the Garmin 1000

What are the Garmin G-1000 LRUs exactly?

The LRUs, line replaceable units, are the discrete components which can be maintained and updated without returning to the manufacturer. The G-1000 Maintenance Manual describes all LRUs associated with the integrated avionics, e.g. the LRUs associated with instrumentation.

There are other LRUs: transponder, communication, navigation, etc, that cannot be detailed here, but the manual has a complete description and you can ask for specific details if necessary.
LRUs location

Where are they located?

LRUs in a large aircraft have dedicated electronic bays. On a Cessna 172, some LRUs have a front plate on the cockpit panel and the rest of the LRU is behind the panel. Remote LRUs are located at various places, often in the avionics shelf where they are air-cooled. The avionics shelf is behind the baggage compartment. Some LRUs are sensors, mounted at the most appropriate location:

Source: Civil Air Patrol
LRU status
LRUs status is indicated on the PFD and MFD, a red cross means the system doesn't receive the expected data fron a particular LRU:

See section 2.1 G1000 Alerting System in the manual for details by LRU. These status are also visible on the dedicated page:



LRUs are Line Replaceable Units. Parts that can be replaced "out on the flight line" without major disassembly.
In the case of the G1000, these are either black boxes themselves for different systems that interact with the G1000 and that it monitors, or in some cases components within the G1000's own electronics boxes that can be swapped out without removing the box itself (if not, then the box itself is the Line Replaceable Unit).
In such cases, these will be circuit cards that can be swapped out by opening a box, removing the card, and plugging in a serviceable one (like changing a RAM card on a personal computer).
This is a widespread practice in the avionics used in large aircraft. You try to get the lowest level of component you can to the LRU level to make repair as fast as possible as cheaply as possible while out on the line (usually at the gate).
What it means in practice is that when something goes wrong during operation, the component that is easiest and cheapest to replace on-the-spot, the LRU, is flagged so maintenance doesn't have to troubleshoot, just change out the part (of course, if that doesn't work, then the troubleshooting has to start in earnest).
